# Adding Bytes Using a Hex Editor

Tags: macos, high-sierra, ms-office, office-365

Due to incompatibility of root account and sandbox, I need to manually disable sandboxing of MS Office applications (so that it can be activated) by changing the value of `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` within the application binary (`/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word`) from `<true/>` to `<false/>`.

However, this change would lead the addition of a byte, and I can't find any documentation on how to insert a byte. I'm using `hexedit`, installed with brew (`brew install hexedit`).

Also, if someone can provide a script to automatically detect and edit that flag, that will be great. Here is an excerpt:

[image]

Comment: Related - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119397/how-to-grant-a-mac-app-permission-to-read-the-whole-filesystem also https://www.mdsec.co.uk/2018/08/escaping-the-sandbox-microsoft-office-on-macos/ & also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/mac/deployment-options-for-office-for-mac

Comment: @nohillside I've done it before, it doesn't. I use hexed.it to insert byte before, but due to whatever reason it doesn't work anymore. I need to use the root account because there are many limitations to an admin account and I have to use sudo all the time.

Comment: You can use `sudo -s` once to start a root shell. Will post an answer regarding byte level editing later (not at home right now)

Comment: What is the sandbox limitation that you are trying to work around? I activated Office and use it extensively without having to bypass sandbox or run into security obstacles.

Comment: @benwiggy I've undeleted some comments as this has come up before :-) The OP didn't go into details though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need additional software for this, the standard `vi` installed by macOS can edit binary files.

```
cd /Applications/Microsoft\ Word.app/Contents/MacOS/
cp Microsoft\ Word Microsoft\ Word.orig
vi -b Microsoft\ Word
```

Now, assuming you are not used to `vi`:

- Type `/app-sandbox` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> to jump to the definition you want to change

[image]

- Press <kbd>Return</kbd> again to move the cursor to the next line
- Type `ct/<false` followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>

[image]

- Type `ZZ` to save and quit

PS: If you get stuck within `vi`, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice and then type `:q!` to quit without saving.

---

If you want to script this, use (at our own risk)

```
vi -b Microsoft\ Word '+/app-sandbox/+1s/true/false/' '+wq'
```

which basically does the same thing as the interactive sequence above in one go.

- `/app-sandbox/+1` makes the following command (the substitution) only apply on the line after the one containing the `app-sandbox` string
- `s/true/false/` is the substitution and replaces `true` by `false`
- `wq` writes the modified file back to disk and quits

Comment: @joyjin Added a way for scripting this, have fun :-)

Comment: A new problem comes out when I modify Microsoft Outlook. Upon launching, it gives me "terminated by signal SIGILL (Illegal instruction)".

Comment: @joyjin Please ask a new question for new problems